# If the discriminant of a cubic polynomial is a square, what can one say about the coefficients of the polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, discriminant

Let $f(x)$ be a monic cubic polynomial over a field K. Suppose that the discriminant of $f$ is a square in K and K has the primitive third roots of unity. What can one say about the coefficients of f? For the moment, by the theory of Kummer extensions, I can say that the splitting field of f is the splitting field of a polynomial of the form $x^3-c$ for some c in K. What else?

I am interested especially in the case in which K is a finite field.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid very little can be said when $K$ is finite. The reason is that there is a **unique** cubic extension $L$ of degree three (extensions of finite fields are always Galois and cyclic).

Consequently $L=K(\root3\of c)$ is the splitting field of **every** irreducible cubic in $K[x]$ and **any** non-cube $c\in K$. Observe that by the same argument the discriminant of every irreducible cubic in $K[x]$ must be a square.

Comment: There is an analogue of Dirichlet's result of equidistribution of primes in the ring $K[x]$. It says that irreducible polynomials are equidistributed among coprime residue classes modulo any polynomial $m(x)\in K[x]$. By selecting, for example $m(x)=x^2$, we can infer that each residue class $a_1x+a_0\pmod {x^2}$ such that $a_0\neq0$ occurs "equally often" as the residue of an irreducible polynomial. But, when we restrict the irreducible polynomials to cubic one, the error terms are considerable.

Comment: Yes I definetely agree but the constraint on the discriminant should say something about the shape of the defining equation?

Comment: Not much, really. If $|K|$ is even, then every element of $K$ is a square. If $|K|=p^n$ is odd, then the assumption that $K$ contains primitive cubic roots of unity says that $3\mid (p^n-1)$. For example, the discriminant of $x^3-c$ is $-27c^2=-3(3c)^2$, which is a square if and only if $-3$ is a square if and only $K$ contains a primitive third root of unity $(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$. You see that the choice of $c$ plays no role.

Comment: We do get a constraint on the coefficients of a cubic, but in this restricted case *irreducible* $\implies$ *square discriminant*.

Comment: That would be very interesting as well!

Comment: May be a counting argument will reveal something? We know that there are $(q^3-q)/3$ irreducible cubics ($q=|K|$) and we can control (using the relative norm $N^L_K$) their constant term. I gotta rush now. Leaving the stage for others...

Comment: Thanks! I will write a comment in case I find out anything